# Showing the limit given the recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $x_1 = 2$. For $j \geq 1$, set $$x_{j+1} = x_j - \frac{x_j^2-2}{2x_j}$$

Show that the sequence $\{x_j\}$ is decreasing and bounded below. What is its limit?

Idea: We can show that the sequence is decreasing by an induction argument. We assume that $\sqrt{2} < x_i \leq 2$ for all $i \leq k$ and show that $\sqrt{2} <  x_{k+1} \leq 2$. This can be easily shown since $x_{j+1} - x_j = - \frac{x_j^2-2}{2x_j}$, and the right hand side of the equation is less than $0$ and greater than or equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$.

By similar idea, it is not hard to show that the sequence converges by the Cauchy criterion. But how do we find the limit of the sequence and show that the sequence converges to this limit?

Comment: Let $l:=\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(x_{n}\right)$. What is the limit of the sequence $\left(x_{n+1}\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$?

Comment: Your induction argument has flaws. The RHS is less than $0$ only if you know that $x_j>\sqrt 2$ (or $-\sqrt 2<x_j<0$)

Comment: Good point. Edited. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you do not need a "similar idea" to show convergence: Every decreasing and bounded from below sequence converges!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261684/check-the-convergence-of-a-n1-sqrta-n-frac4a-n-where-a-1-4/1261761#1261761, aka "Lamere Ladder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ converge, it converge to a fixed point of $f$.

Hence the limit verify

$L = L - \frac{L^2-2}{2L}$

And it follow that $L=\sqrt{2}$

Your sequence is basically the Newton's method applied to the function $f(x)=x^2-2$

Comment: Thank you for your response. But can we provide a $(\epsilon, \sigma)$ proof though?

Comment: @LKSR what for?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can we show that the sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$ by an $(\epsilon, \sigma)$ argument?

Comment: @LKSR That would be a waste of effort

Comment: @LKSR As the answer clearly states, the problem of interest is identical to using the Newton-Raphson Method to determine the root of $x^2-2$.  So, you should refer to the literature on the NR method.

Comment: @tyyss Solid answer +1