# How to determine the outcome of the recursive sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{\operatorname{abs}\left(a_{n-1}\right)-1}$

Tags: recursion, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration

Depending on the starting value, the end result of this iterative sequence appears to be very variable, for example, if the starting value $a_0\ =\frac{b}{c}$ where $b$ and $c$ are integers, then eventually the sequence appears to always reach 0, and then infinity afterwards, ending the sequence.

Another situation is if the starting value is in the form $\frac{b+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ where $b$ is an integer, this now appears to converge to either $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or ends up switching between $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ endlessly.

Yet again another situation, where the starting value is not rational and not in the form I described previously, sometimes other starting values experience periodicity e.g. for $a_0 = \sqrt{3}$ there are only 9 values that the sequence can take. Also similar to this category, some values are not initially periodic but eventually hit a value which is; e.g.  $a_0 = 3-\sqrt{3}$ .

Outside of these categories, there are some which I imagine should never converge e.g. $\pi$ , although it does have a tendency to tend towards $-1$ and then towards a very large number, before cycling back to a small one again.

EDIT: this is an interesting visualisation for the $\sqrt{3}$ case (see figure 1)

EDIT 2: this is another interesting discovery, if i put $f(x)=x$ for n iterations in a graphing calculator and record all of the points where the graph $y=x$ intersects the other graph, all of these points are the values of $x_0$ which are periodic of period n (see figure 3, i have written the equation for 9 iterations and found a fixed point at $\sqrt{3}$).

I also notice that the number of fixed points appears to be getting much larger each time, and these fixed points are particularly dense around the golden ratio *phi*  and this might indicate that after an arbitrarily large number of iterations, we have an arbitrarily large number of fixed points, though I don't know if this would cover all algebraic numbers . However, some other values for $x_0$ may not themselves be periodic, but eventually reach one that is e.g. $3+\sqrt{2}$ (see figure 2)

[image: figure 1]
(figure 1)

[image: figure 2]
(figure 2)

[image: figure 3]
(figure 3)

My question is, can it be

a.) Proven/disproven that for starting value a/b , the sequence will eventually  reach 0?

b.) Proven/disproven that for any algebraic number, the sequence is eventually finitely periodic, and if so, is there are a way of determining its period?

c.) Proven/disproven that the sequence does not converge for transcendental numbers?

Any information on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to list some examples http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261684/check-the-convergence-of-a-n1-sqrta-n-frac4a-n-where-a-1-4/1261761#1261761, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705697/why-does-this-sequence-converge-to-%CF%86/1705752#1705752 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701935/let-a-n-cosa-n-1-l-a-1-a-2-a-n-is-there-an-a-0-such-that-l/1702090#1702090

Comment: So, in this case you are dealing with $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|-1}$

Answer (score 5):

Since the iterating map $f : a \mapsto \frac 1 {|a|-1}$ is a piecewise rational homography, and because rational homographies are a group under composition, any iterate of $f$ is again a piecewise rational homography.

Then, cycles can only occur at a fixpoint of one of those homographies, and their fixpoints are quadratic numbers : if $x = \frac {ax+b}{cx+d}$ for rational $a,b,c,d$, then $cx^2+(d-a)x-b = 0$, which is a quadratic equation in $x$ with rational coefficients.

---

We can count the number of cycles for each $n$, and also see what possible sequence of sign you can get.

Split the circle $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ into four parts $A=[\infty ; -1],B=[-1;0],C=[0;1],D=[1;\infty]$. $f$ sends $A$ and $D$ on $C \cup D$, and sends $B$ and $C$ on $A$.

With this we can quickly determine by induction that if $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1, \ldots$ is the Fibonacci sequence,
$f^{\circ n}$ sends $A$ and $D$ on ($F_{n-1}$ times $A$ and $F_n$ times $C$ and $D$) ; and it sends $B$ and $C$ on ($F_{n-2}$ times $A$ and $F_{n-1}$ times $C$ and $D$).

Each time you have a piece of $f^{\circ n}$ sending a subinterval of $A$ onto a whole $A$, you get exactly one fixpoint in that interval, and the same goes for $B,C,D$.
This gives you $F_{n-1} + F_{n-1} + F_n$ fixpoints in total for every piece of $f^{\circ n}$. That's the Fibonacci-like sequence $1,3,4,7,11,18,\ldots$

(except for the cycle $0 \mapsto -1 \mapsto \infty \mapsto 0$, they all have to be inside the intervals so they are only counted once. But so is this one because we only count the "half" of $0$ that occurs in $C$)

By looking at that Fibonacci-like sequence then removing the smaller cycles coming from divisors of $n$, you get $1,1,1,1,2,2,\ldots$ cycles of length exactly $1,2,3,4,5,6\ldots$

Moreover, a number is completely determined by which intervals $C,A,D$ the sequence goes through. Any $C$ is followed by a $A$, while $A$ or $D$ can be followed by $C$ or $D$.

Going back to signs, knowing the sequence of intervals is the same as knowing the sequence of signs. A negative sign correspond to a $C$, a positive sign correspond to $C$ or $D$ according to if the next sign is positive or not, so the possible sign sequences are every possible sequence where there is no consecutive $-$ sign, and again, an irrational number is completely determined by the sequence of signs it goes through

If you are on a positive real, then you will see a bunch of $CA (+-)$ and $D (+)$, and of course, numbers that are on cycles correspond to periodic sequences.

For example the $4$-cycle correspond to repeating $CADD (+-++)$ and two $5$-cycles correspond to $CACAD (+-+-+)$ and $CADDD (+-+++)$

---

If you know about continued fractions, they come from a similar piecewise homography $g$ on positive real numbers ($g(x) = x-1$ if $x \ge 1$ and $g(x) = \frac 1x$ if $0 < x \le 1$).

In fact, they are very much intertwined.
If $2 \le x$ then $f(x) = \frac 1{x-1} > 0$, $f(f(x)) = \frac{1-x}{x-2} < 0$, and $f(f(f(x))) = x-2 = g(g(x))$

If $1 \le x \le 2$ then $f(x) = \frac 1{x-1} = g(g(x))$

If $0 \le x \le 1$ then $f(x) = \frac {-1}{1-x} < 0$, $f(f(x)) = \frac{1-x}x = \frac 1x - 1 = g(g(x))$

So iterating $f$ on some number will reach (among others), all the iterates of $g\circ g$ on that number.

In particular, if you start on a positive real, you reach large a number if and only if you reach a large number when computing the continued fraction of that real (that's what you see happening with $\pi$ for example)

In particular, any quadratic number has a continued fraction which is eventually periodic, so under your iteration, their trajectory will be eventually periodic as well : quadratic numbers correspond exactly to eventually periodic sign sequences.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me change your problem statement from $\displaystyle a_{n+1}={1\over|a_n|-1}$ to $\displaystyle a_{n+1}={1\over|a_n-1|}$. It is equivalent in anything but the sign (that is, if $a_0>0$), and will let us stay conveniently on the positive half-line.

Now suppose we have a rational number $a_1={p\over q}$. Let's define a norm: $\max(p,q)$. What will become of it? There are two distinct cases:

$$\begin{align}a_1>1\;\Rightarrow\;p>q\;\Rightarrow\;\; a_2={q\over p-q}\\
a_1<1\;\Rightarrow\;p<q\;\Rightarrow\;\; a_2={q\over q-p}
\end{align}$$
So the norm strictly decreases after any term which is greater than 1, and does not change after a term which is less than 1. Note that a term less than 1 is always immediately followed by a term greater than 1 (the reverse is not true), so making **two** steps is guaranteed to decrease the norm. Note also that there are only so many rational numbers with given norm, so this descent can't be infinite; it must end somewhere, and we seem to know where.

Now let's deal with the periodic points. $f(x)$ is piecewise linear-fractional, hence so are all its iterations. In other words, $f(f(\dots(x)\dots))$ is essentially $ax+b\over cx+d$, only its domain consists of multiple intervals, and the coefficients depend on the interval. Well, but then equating this to $x$ is equivalent to a quadratic equation (or rather a bunch thereof, one for each interval), and their roots, however many, are all **quadratic irrationalities**. That's it; there can be no other periodic points. Even the algebraic numbers of higher degree won't do.

I don't quite see why **all** quadratic irrationalities must eventually converge to some cycle, but it seems they do. Let's think of it later.

Comment: It is definitely not true that $1\over|a_n|-1$ and ${1\over|a_n-1|}$ are "equivalent in anything but the sign" when $a_n$ is negative. Your answer needs to be corrected on that point.

Comment: $a_n$ in my version can never be negative, except $a_0$, for which I'll add a note now.

Comment: If, for example, $a_0=-10$, the OP's sequence will have $a_1=\frac{1}{9}$ while your sequence will have $a_1=\frac{1}{11}$. It is not true that $\frac{1}{9}$ and $\frac{1}{11}$ are  "equivalent in anything but the sign"

Comment: Right, that's why I just added the note to the effect $a_0>0$. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, given integers are a particular case of $\frac{a}{b}$ let's look at the following case, $n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 2$, then $x_0=n \rightarrow \frac{1}{n-1} \rightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n-1}-1}=\frac{n-1}{2-n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\left|\frac{n-1}{2-n}\right|-1}=n-2$. Similar fate will have a starting point $x_0=-n$.
So

- if we start with an even $2p$ after $3$ iterations $\rightarrow 2(p-1)$, after $3$ iterations $\rightarrow 2(p-2)$ ... $\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1\rightarrow \infty$
- if we start with an odd $2p+1$ after $3$ iterations $\rightarrow 2(p-1)+1$, after $3$ iterations $\rightarrow 2(p-2)+1$ ... $\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \rightarrow -2 \rightarrow 1  \rightarrow \infty$

Integers end up at infinity. Arguably, we could say that the next iteration will throw them at $0$, but I think it's a speculation, thus this should qualify as a counter-example for a)

Other than that, I agree with @mercio regarding the similarity with continued fractions. Imagine $$\alpha=a_0+\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+...}}=a_0+\frac{1}{\beta}$$

- if $a_0=2p+1$, $\alpha \rightarrow$ after $3$ iterations $\alpha-2=a_0-2+\frac{1}{\beta} \rightarrow $ ... $\rightarrow 3+\frac{1}{\beta} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{\beta}}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{\beta}}-1}=\frac{2+\frac{1}{\beta}}{-1-\frac{1}{\beta}}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{2+\frac{1}{\beta}}{1+\frac{1}{\beta}}-1}=1+\frac{1}{\beta}\rightarrow \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\beta}-1}=\beta=a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+...}$
- if $a_0=2p$, $\alpha \rightarrow$ after $3$ iterations $\alpha-2=a_0-2+\frac{1}{\beta} \rightarrow $ ... $\rightarrow 2+\frac{1}{\beta} \rightarrow \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\beta}}\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\beta}}-1}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{\beta}}{-\frac{1}{\beta}}=-\beta-1\rightarrow \frac{1}{\beta+1-1} \rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}=\frac{\beta}{1-\beta} \rightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{\beta}{\beta-1}-1}=\beta-1=a_1-1+\frac{1}{a_2+...}$, this is of course assuming $a_1>0$.

Then there is this [book by Khinchin](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Continued-Fractions-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486696308) which states that "any quadratic irrational number has a periodic continued fraction" as Theorem 28.